# Implement GWT Code into Cordova Phonegap Project

Tags: gwt, cordova

I have created one GWT sample project for Web Application.
I have also created one sample Android Phonegap Application with the help of Cordova.

GWT is basically compile and convert java code to javascript.

For Phonegap application, html+css+js files are used for operations.

So How can I use that GWT project and convert it into javascript or phonegap plug-in..?

So please, Can anyone describe me process and steps to follow for GWT project used in phonegap application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.m-gwt.com

It is a GWT framework for building mobile apps with GWT built by one of the GWT Steering Committee members.

You may want to read the official GWT blog on mgwt: http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.de/2012/07/gwt-support-for-mobile-app-development.html